# Anyone used "Windows Services for UNIX"?

Tags: windows, unix

Is there anyone used "Windows Services for UNIX" or SFU? Can it be used instead of CYGWIN? Do you recommend? Any introductory tutorial for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Windows Services for Unix to be able to mount a NFS drive as a network drive.

From my experience those services and what you get out of cygwin are two separate things.

Comment: I've used them briefly and agree it's very different from cygwin. SFU is mostly for interoperability. We tried serving NIS from AD, which works but with inconveniences (user names and group names must be distinct)

Comment: I used it for a while. I know that it can create problems with normal windows command line in some cases. I personally like Cygwin more.

Comment: @pjc50  How do you use it - does it place an ls.exe somewhere?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35512 I think it does exactly that; also you get a ksh and a csh (but not a Bourne shell, that would be too useful). It's been a long time since I used it and would suggest Cygwin if you just want a UNIXy environment.